# How to get access to admin urls on production google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, admin

I have uploaded a gae app for testing to production. I need to est the admin access. I have added two email addresses via permissions and set them as owners.

I have a decorator which is called to check admin user and this is called properly on the local development machine.

```
def admin_required(handler):
    """
         Decorator for checking if there's an admin user
         Assigned Google App admin only NOT users with admin permissions
    """

    def check_admin(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Admin decorator
        """
        logging.info(users.is_current_user_admin())
        if not users.is_current_user_admin():
            self.redirect_to('home')
        else:
            return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return check_admin
```

I login to my app using one of the emails in permissions and then try to access an admin page and get the following:

Error: Unauthorized
Your client does not have permission to the requested URL /admin/delete-search-indexes.

Am I missing something simple or is it that Google have to make everything difficult to understand?

Comment: Why don't you use `login: admin` in the `app.yaml` file?

Comment: Is that strictly required if I have a decorator as shown? The decorator works fine on the locale machine, is there an issue with users.is_current_user_admin() on production?

Comment: - url: /admin.*
  script: main.app
  login: admin
  auth_fail_action: unauthorized

Comment: Is that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this resolved by changing the app.yaml setting to

```
- url: /admin.*
  script: main.app
  login: admin
  auth_fail_action: redirect
```

and keeping the decorator as is